# What does [ERROR]objGlobalMap mean

Tags: apex, class, error-messages

I Am trying to debug and have the following error mean, as I dont see this in Line 8 of my Class: `USER_DEBUG [8]|ERROR|objGlobalMap:::{acceptedeventrelation=AcceptedEventRelation, account=Account, accountcontactrole=AccountContactRole, accountfeed=AccountFeed, accounthistory=AccountHistory, accountpartner=AccountPartner, accountshare=AccountShare, actionlinkgrouptemplate=ActionLinkGroupTemplate, actionlinktemplate=ActionLinkTemplate, activityhistory=ActivityHistory, ...}`

Comment: It looks very much like someone has done a `System.debug` and dumped the contents of a Map. It could be from line 8 of another Apex class. Try using the developer console "Search in Files" to search for the string 'objGlobalMap:::'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code used System.debug with the optional first parameter for severity:

```
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, message);
```

Logging Level is rarely used and often abused. It most likely wasn't an error path, but the developer wanted it to appear when using ERROR level logging (which produces smaller logs).